# What is the correct syntax for Walrus operator with ternary operator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-operator, walrus-operator

Looking at [Python-Dev](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-September/056846.html) and [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator), Python's ternary operator equivalent is:

```
a if condition else b
```

Looking at [PEP-572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) and [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57309129/walrus-operator-example-in-pep572), I understand what Walrus operator is:

```
:=
```

Now I'm trying to to combine the "walrus operator's assignment" and "ternary operator's conditional check" into a single statement, something like:

```
other_func(a) if (a := some_func(some_input)) else b
```

For example, please consider the below snippet:

```
do_something(list_of_roles) if list_of_roles := get_role_list(username) else "Role list is [] empty"
```

I'm failing to wrap my mind around the syntax. Having tried various combinations, every time the interpreter throws `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. My python version is 3.8.3.

My question is **What is the correct syntax to embed walrus operator within ternary operator?**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Syntactically, you are just missing a pair of parenthesis.

```
do_something(list_of_roles) if (list_of_roles := get_role_list(username)) else "Role list is [] empty"
```

---

If you look at the grammar, `:=` is defined as part of a high-level `namedexpr_test` construct:

```
namedexpr_test: test [':=' test]
```

while a conditional expression is a kind of `test`:

```
test: or_test ['if' or_test 'else' test] | lambdef
```

This means that `:=` cannot be used *in* a conditional expression unless it occurs inside a nested expression.

Comment: When in doubt, add some parentheses.  A rule I've found very handy over the years.

Answer (score 13):

For someone looking for a short answer or failing to grasp the accepted answer quickly like I did:

```py
>>> variable = foo if (foo := 'parentheses!!') else 'otherwise'
>>> #                 ▲                      ▲
>>> #                 ╰──────────────────────╯
>>> variable
parentheses!!
```