# Python defined or operator

Tags: python

Is there some conditional operator in Python which would evaluate the first operand and return its value if it's not `None`, or if it's `None`, evaluate and return the second operand?  I know that `a or b` can almost do this, except that it does not strictly distinguish `None` and `False`.  Looking for something similar to `//` operator in Perl.

The goal is to write both `a` and `b` only once, therefore alternative `a if a is not None else b` doesn't work either - both `a` and `b` can be expensive expressions.

Comment: You can write a function to do this.

Comment: PEP 505 proposes such an operator (`a ?? b`), but it's suspended in limbo.

Comment: Your title says "defined", your text says "not `None`. Which one is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using the walrus operator?

```py
tmp if (tmp := a()) is not None else b()
```

It will be faster than writing your own function, as function calls in Python incur a large overhead.

Comment: Elvis is `?:`, `:=` is walrus.

Comment: Oops :/ it's been a long day

Answer (score 1):

This works: `a_ if (a_ := a) is not None else b` - would this not account for a being only evaluated once?

Also see: [What is the correct syntax for Walrus operator with ternary operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63289494/what-is-the-correct-syntax-for-walrus-operator-with-ternary-operator)

Comment: Pretty sure that's invalid, since order of operations will make that `(a_ := (a is not None))`. I think that should be `(a_ := a) is not None`